# How to undo init in a cloned git repository

Tags: git, init

I have a git repository cloned from the remote master. I ran init on the local cloned copy by mistake, my bad. So its now a brand new repo to git and git remote etc don't show any connection to the remote origin, of course. How can I 'reparent' or tell it again what's its remote origin is/was?

Comment: If you do not have any changes which needs to be pushed to your origin, then just clone the repo one more time on new location.

Comment: I have returned to this project after a bit so I am not sure if I had changes that needed to be committed. I could clone another copy and do a tree diff to find out but I wanted to know if there is a combination of git commands that would let me point the existing clone back to the remote.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you run `git init` in a cloned repository. Something changes but in most cases it's just okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) in an existing repository does not produce any harm. The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) says:

> Running `git init` in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for rerunning `git init` is to pick up newly added templates (or to move the repository to another place if `--separate-git-dir` is given).

At least it doesn't remove the remotes, as you say. You probably ran `git init` in a subdirectory and it created a new repository there. In that case, `git` has created a hidden `.git/` folder in that subdirectory. Find it and remove it.

If this is not the case and the repository you cloned was affected somehow, there is a simple way to repair it. Add the original repo as a remote and fetch all the commits from it again.

```
git remote add origin url-of-the-repo-you-cloned-before
git fetch origin
```

Now your repo contains all the commits that are present in the remote repository. What you do next depends on what you did before you found out the commits are gone. Run `git status` to decide. If you are on the correct branch then you can continue working and commit at some point. If you are not on the branch you want (or you are not on a branch at all) then you can try to `git checkout` the branch you need. If it doesn't work because it would replace files that you modified and didn't commit then you have to stash your changes, checkout the new branch and pop the changes from the stash ([`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), [`git checkout correct-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), [`git stash pop`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)).

Comment: Thank you @LeGEC for editing. The sentence you added clarifies a paragraph that otherwise could bring more troubles than help to a less-experienced Git user.

Comment: you're welcome :) Your answer was already pretty complete, and I woudln't have thought about the possibility of running `git init` in a subdir

Comment: Thanks axiac and LeGEC! That's what I had done, run the command (programmatically) in a level below the TOP, doh!